# Base 36 to Base 10 conversion using SQL only

Tags: sql, oracle, base36

A situation has arisen where I need to perform a base 36 to base 10 conversion, in the context of a SQL statement.   There doesn't appear to be anything built into Oracle 9, or Oracle 10 to address this sort of thing.  My Google-Fu, and AskTom suggest creating a pl/sql function to deal with the task.  That is not an option for me at this point.  **I am looking for suggestions on an approach to take that might help me solve this issue.**

To put this into a visual form...

```
WITH
Base36Values AS
(
    SELECT '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' myBase36 FROM DUAL
),
TestValues AS
(
    SELECT '01Z' BASE36_VALUE,
            71   BASE10_VALUE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM Base36Values,
     TestValues
```

**I am looking for something to calculate the value 71, based on the input 01Z.**
EDIT - that is backwards... given 01Z translate it to 71.

As a bribe, each useful answer gets a free upvote.

Thanks

Evil.

Comment: I'm just curious (I've always wanted find an excuse to use different bases to store data); what is the base 36 data used for?

Comment: And I'm curious why this has to be done in SQL, that's not really common.

Comment: The advantage of base 36 is that you can use an embedded device which has a limited keyboard to provide input. Then, interpreting it as base36 instead as string is more efficient because of the size and moreover you can calculate with it using default functions.

Comment: +1, one of the more interesting questions I've seen posed lately

Comment: @david It's a unique identifier from a legacy system.  Just think of it as an encoded sequence number.
@georg It's a political thing.  Choose your battles and all that.
@dcookie thank you....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
select sum(position_value) from
(
  select power(36,position-1) * case when digit between '0' and '9' 
                                     then to_number(digit)
                                     else 10 + ascii(digit) - ascii('A')
                                end
          as position_value
    from (
          select substr(input_string,length(input_string)+1-level,1) digit, 
                 level position
            from (select '01Z' input_string from dual)
            connect by level <= length(input_string)
         )
)
```

Comment: +1, saweeeeeet! Excellent illustration of the use of the connect by level syntax.

Comment: Yes.  Replace the base36 string, by a case statement.  Thank you Dave.

Answer (score 6):

For T-SQL the following logic will perform the task that the Oracle code above does. This is generic general solution and will support Base-X to Base-10:

```
select
    sum(power(base,pos-1) *
            case when substring(cnv,pos,1) between '0' and '9' then 
                cast(substring(cnv,pos,1) as int) 
            else 10 + ascii(upper(substring(cnv,pos,1))) - ascii('A') end)
    from (values(reverse('01Z'), 36)) as t(cnv,base)
        left join (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) as x(pos)
            on pos <= len(cnv)
```

To use with other bases just use:

```
from (select cnv = reverse('FF'), base=16) as t
```

or

```
from (select cnv = reverse('101'), base=2) as t
```

Note that to support strings longer than 6 you would need to add more values to the position vector.