# what is the Algorithm used to identify the scenario

Tags: algorithm

I have scenario where for any given number i need to identify the corresponding 2 to the power  of value.
for example if the given number is 12:

12 is represented in 2 to the power as: 2 to the power of 3 and 2 to the power of 2
  5 is represented in 2 to the power as: 2 to the power of 2 and 2 to the power of 0

Can i know the algorithm named on this scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's name is radix conversion. Convert your number to binary radix and you'll get your sum of power of `2`. For example,

```
12 = 1100
```

That means:

```
     1           1          0         0
     ^           ^          ^         ^
     |           |          |         |
12 = 1 * (2^3) + 1* (2^2) + 0*(2^1) + 0*(2^0)
            |          |         |         |
            V          V         V         V
            3          2         1         0
```

-it's by definition of what [radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) (numeral base) is.

Comment: Depends of your DBMS. In MySQL, there's [`CONV()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv), for example

Comment: what is the matching function in SQL Server for CONV()

Comment: I'm not SQL Server expert, but as far as I know, there's no in-built equivalent for that. Instead you'll have to use something like [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=109916) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568668/base-36-to-base-10-conversion-using-sql-only)