# How generate oracle string sequence?

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I need generate unique identifiers which must be no longer then 5 length, because of it numbers don't fit, it there any way generate unique strings in oracle database?

Comment: How many values do you need to be able to represent? Using a normal sequence but storing the hex equivalent would take you from 100,000 values to 1,048,756, but that might still be too low? Using 26 characters would give 11,881,376 possible values; including digits would give 60,466,176. But more complicated that converting a sequence.

Comment: why the limitation on 5? (schema change would make more sense imo).  Also, even if you stick with the 5 limitation, how many unique values do you require?  Probably best to change the schema and use either a number or sys_guid.

Comment: The lemetation on 5 is because of documentation from client for ready rest api, I need more then ten billions objects.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use Base 36: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36

SQL: [Base 36 to Base 10 conversion using SQL only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568668/base-36-to-base-10-conversion-using-sql-only)

Due to the comments to this answer, I'm adding an example:

This function converts base 10 number to the base which consists of letters.

```
create or replace 
function basen(n10 in number, letters in varchar2) return varchar2 as 
  s       varchar2(1000);
  len     number := length(letters);
  base10  number := n10;
begin
  if len <= 0 then
    return null;
  end if;

  loop
    if base10 < len then 
      return substr(letters, base10+1, 1) || s;
    end if;
    s := substr(letters, mod(base10, len)+1,1) || s;
    base10 := floor(base10 / len);
  end loop;

  return s;
end baseN;
```

This function converts from base10 to base36:

```
create or replace function base36(n10 in number) return varchar2 as 
begin
  return basen(n10, '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
end base36;
```

You may create a common sequence with the appropriate MINVALUE and MAXVALUE and use one of the methods above in the trigger, SQL etc.

Answer (score 2):

This method to use numbers in HEX format.

```
select to_char(seq.nextval, 'fm0XXXX')
  from dual;
```

Or this more compact method to use all symbols between ASCII code 33 and 122:

```
select num,
       chr(33 + mod(floor(num/(90*90*90*90)), 90))||
       chr(33 + mod(floor(num/(90*90*90)), 90))||
       chr(33 + mod(floor(num/(90*90)),90))||
       chr(33 + mod(floor(num/90),90))||
       chr(33 + mod(num,90)) as x00000
 from (select seq.nextval as num 
         from dual);
```

Basically this is a representation of 90-based number.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
http://www.deep-data-mining.com/2012/06/five-ways-of-creating-unique-record.html

This bit looks useful:

**According to Oracle document, SYS_GUID generates and returns a globally unique identifier (RAW value) made up of 16 bytes.**

For example, on our Oracle system, I can do this:

```
select sys_guid() uniq_id from dual;
```

And get this:

```
059D828192804EABE05400144FFB6CA7
```

Next time I get:

```
059D828192A34EABE05400144FFB6CA7
```

Some of the numbers increment each time.

I could limit that to 5 characters, including the bits of the string which change each time it runs:

```
select substr(sys_guid(),9,5) uniq_id from dual;
```

To get e.g.

```
92D14
```

Comment: As I see you just cut the generated string and it can be not unique.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I think my answer was probably a load of old rubbish :-\ Sorry about that. I thought the number would be unique, but maybe it wouldn't be after all, I'm not sure. Sorry for wasting time.